# Debugging a function call that hangs in Erlang

Tags: debugging, erlang, freeze

It seems as if I have a caused a deadlock somewhere either in my code or in code that I'm using, but I am not sure how to debug it. Since I have no clue where the problem is and I can make the system almost completely idle, I think that it would be useful to see a trace of all functions and messages leading up to the hang. It looks like `dbg` provides some help in tracing, but I don't see how to configure it for such a broad trace. Is such a trace possible with `dbg` or are there other ways of debugging hangs in Erlang that are better?

Comment: What kind of application you are working on ? What is it doing before it hangs ? Do you have some sample code ?

Comment: The hang occurs in a cowboy-based application when I call application:stop/1. I was debating about posting more code, but my hope was to get a more generic answer for how people debug these issues rather than a specific solution to my current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `dbg`.  While there is a conventional debugger as mentioned in another answer its usefulness is very limited for concurrent programs since it cause plenty of timeouts usually.

To overcome the hurdle of using `dbg` I recommend the following resources:

[All answers are interesting here but especially the user_default in the linked one helps also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954894/using-trace-and-dbg-in-erlang/2831375#2831375)

[Example what can be done by handling the trace messages yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126458/dbgtracer-visualizing-recursive-functions-e-g-by-indenting/5128876#5128876) which can be useful in hard to debug cases.

[Continuously updated links and nodes about Erlangs dbg](https://pinboard.in/u:peerst/t:erlang/t:dbg/)

If you need to use `dbg` in production I recommend using [redbug](https://code.google.com/p/eper/wiki/redbug) which helps you not crash your node.  [Blogpost about using redbug](http://jlouisramblings.blogspot.de/2010/11/tracing-erlang-programs-for-fun-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [Erlang Debugger](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/debugger/debugger_chapter.html)?

Comment: I tried, but my setup doesn't seem ideal for it. My code runs on a remote node and I can't run the debugger locally on that node. I may just need to dig through the docs more since it seems like using the debugger on remote nodes would be possible in Erlang. I'll try after I work through the dbg recommendation.