# How to debug an Elixir application in production?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

This is not particularly about my current problem, but more like in general. Sometimes I have a problem that only happens in production configuration, and I'd like to debug it there. What is the best way to approach that in Elixir? Production runs without a graphical environment (docker).

In dev I can use IEX.pry, but since mix is unavailable in production, that does not seem to be an option.

For Erlang https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413344/1561489 mentions dbg and redbug, but even if they can be used, I would need help on applying them to Elixir code.

Comment: Use specific logs, you can always replace the default backend for logs - console - for something suitable for your needs.

Comment: Add `Logger.error` everywhere you want to debug, re-deploy and watch logs. I also want to hear about better approach.

Comment: You can also try to identify exact differences between your production system and your debug system and eliminate them. As far as I know there's no such thing as a "debug" build in terms of BEAM code so the code should be the same between the two environments.

Comment: How are you running the app in production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, start a local node running iex on your dev machine using `iex -S mix`. If you don't want the application that's running locally to cause breakpoints to be activated, you need to disable the app from starting locally. To do this, you can simply comment out the `application` function in `mix.exs` or run `iex -S mix run --no-start`.

Next, you need to connect to the remote node running on docker from iex on your dev node using `Node.connect(:"remote@hostname")`. In order to do this, you have to make sure both the epmd and the node ports on the remote machine are reachable from your local node.

Finally, once your nodes are connected, from the local iex, run `:debugger.start()` which opens the debugger with the GUI. Now in the local iex, run `:int.ni(<Module you want to debug>)` and it will make the module visible to the debugger and you can go ahead and add breakpoints and start debugging.

You can find a tutorial with steps and screenshots [here](https://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2017-11-22-elixir-remote-debugging/).

Comment: I'd like to add the following from the IEx manual: "connecting to remote shells is so common that we provide a shortcut via the command line as well: `$ iex --sname baz --remsh foo@HOST`"

Answer (score 3):

In the case that you are running your production on AWS, then you should first and foremost leverage `CloudWatch` to your advantage.
In your `elixir` code, configure your logger like this:

```
config :logger,
  handle_otp_reports: true,
  handle_sasl_reports: true,
  metadata: [:application, :module, :function, :file, :line]

config :logger,
  backends: [
    {LoggerFileBackend, :shared_error}
  ]

config :logger, :shared_error,
  path: "#{logging_dir}/verbose-error.log",
  level: :error
```

Inside your Dockerfile, configure an environment variable for where exactly `erl_crash.dump` gets written to, such as: 
`ERL_CRASH_DUMP=/opt/log/erl_crash.dump`

Then configure `awslogs` inside a `.config` file under `.ebextensions` as follows:

```
files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/stdout.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [erl_crash.dump]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/your_app/erl_crash.dump
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/erl_crash.dump

      [verbose-error.log]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/your_app/verbose-error.log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/verbose-error.log
```

And ensure that you set a volume to your docker under `Dockerrun.aws.json`

```
  "Logging": "/var/log",
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/var/log",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/opt/log"
    }
  ],
```

After that, you can inspect your error messages under `CloudWatch`.
Now, if you are using `ElasticBeanstalk`(which my example above implicitly implies) with `Docker` deployment as opposed to `AWS ECS`, then the logs of `std_input` are redirected by default to `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log` inside `CloudWatch`.

The main purpose of `erl_crash.dump` is to at least know when your application crashed, thereby taking the container down. `AWS EB` will normally restart the container, thus keeping you ignorant about the restart. This understanding can also be obtained from other docker related logs, and you can configure alarms to listen for them and be notified accordingly when your docker had to restart. But another advantage of logging `erl_crash.dump` to CloudWatch is that if need be, you can always export it later to S3, download the file and import it inside `:observer` to do analysis of what went wrong.

If after consulting the logs, you still require a more intimate interaction with your production application, then you need to leverage `remsh` to your node. If you use `distillery`, you would configure the `cookie` and the `node name` of your production application with your release like this:

inside `rel/confix.exs`, set cookie:

```
environment :prod do
  set include_erts: false
  set include_src: false
  set cookie: :"my_cookie"
end
```

and under `rel/templates/vm.args.eex` you set variables:

```
-name <%= node_name %>
-setcookie <%= release.profile.cookie %>
```

and inside `rel/config.exs`, you set release like this:

```
release :my_app do
  set version: "0.1.0"

  set overlays: [
    {:template, "rel/templates/vm.args.eex", "releases/<%= release_version %>/vm.args"}
  ]

  set overlay_vars: [
    node_name: "p@127.0.0.1",
  ]
```

Then you can directly connect to your production node running inside docker by first ssh-ing inside the EC2-instance that houses the docker container, and run the following:

```
CONTAINER_ID=$(sudo docker ps --format '{{.ID}}')
sudo docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID bash -c "iex --name q@127.0.0.1 --cookie my_cookie"
```

Once inside, you can then try to poke around or `if need be`, at your own peril inject modified code dynamically of the module you would like to inspect. An easy way to do that would be to create a file inside the container and to invoke a `Node.spawn_link target_node, fn Code.eval_file(file_name, path) end`

In the case your production node is already running and you do not know the cookie, you can go inside your running container and do a `ps aux > t.log` and do a `cat t.log` to figure out what random cookie has been applied and use accordingly.

Docker serves as an impediment to the way `epmd` is able to communicate with other nodes. The best therefore would be to rather create your own `AWS AMI` image using `Packer` and do bare metal deployments instead.

Amazon has recently released a new feature to `AWS ECS`, [AWS VPC Networking Mode](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-ecs-introduces-awsvpc-networking-mode-for-containers-to-support-full-networking-capabilities/), which perhaps may facilitate inter-container `epmd` communication and thus connecting to your node directly. I have not tried it out as yet, I may be wrong.

In the case that you are running on a provider other than AWS, then figuring out how to get easy access to your remote logs with some `SSM agent` or some other service is a must.

Comment: The above is a general overview, pedantic details may be missing and are left as an exercise to the reader : )

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some sort of exception handling tools, so far I am having great experiences on [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-elixir).